# Problem with serial driver for CH340G board

Tags: serial, arduino-nano

I bought a `USB Nano V3.0 ATmega328 16M 5V Micro-controller CH340G board For Arduino` and tried it with Arduino 1.6.6 on my MacBook Pro running OS X 10.11.1

The USB serial could not be seen. I searched on the web and found a few posts about this board, and downloaded http://www.wch.cn/download/CH341SER_MAC_ZIP.html

Most of the instructions were in Chinese, but the driver `CH341SER_MAC.ZIP 资料类型：应用资料 资料大小：250KB 资料版本：1.1 更新时间：2013-12-25` seemed to install, but I cannot seem to find any `/dev/tty` and Arduino can't see any serial ports.

Has anyone had any success with this. (The seller has sold 18000 of these so someone may have got it working.)

Comment: I'm not sure if it's the answer, but your driver is for the CH341, not the CH340G

Comment: Well, that's what you get for buying cheap clones. Those chips are notoriously difficult to get working with OS X. Some have done it, some have failed miserably. Simplest just to cut your losses and buy a *real* Arduino.

Comment: I suggest you do not give overly great weight to (the great*) Majenko's advertising for "real" Arduino's. While there are indeed many substandard 'clones' the Arduino platform is, by the originator's intentions, open source, and it does much violence to their philosophy and intended open-ness of the design to disclaim "realness" for all products not made by one or two companies. The seller of the product should be able to provide drivers that work with any mainstream O/S. If the do not and cannot then by all means include them on Majenko's no-go list. I have had excellent results with ....

Comment: .... Baite electronics  Arduino compatible products. Great name ! :-). Also great price and rapid delivery (in my experience). I am not associated with the company in any way and gain nothing financially (or any other way) from recommending them. || * I consider Majenko to be very highly capable a superb source of technical advice. We may disagree on some unimportant secondary issues :-).

Comment: @FuaZe, the 340 and 341 are very similar, most drivers support both.

Comment: These cheap clones always give me a problem on a *Mac*, but when I have plugged them into a PC (of any age) they have always worked as expected. Don't get me wrong, I love Macs, but sometimes you *have to* use a PC...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Using different search criteria I found http://kiguino.moos.io/2014/12/31/how-to-use-arduino-nano-mini-pro-with-CH340G-on-mac-osx-yosemite.html

This indicated a newer driver for OSX 10.9 and above at:-
http://kiguino.moos.io/downloads/CH34x_Install.zip

It is now working OK.

PS This was probably a Mac question, but I will answer as it is mainly of interest to Arduino users.

PPS The board worked on my Raspberry Pi which had the driver installed.

WARNING

### The driver worked on `OS X 10.11` but after upgrading to `OS X 10.11.2` when I plug the USB cable into the Mac it causes a crash. This may or may not be related to the upgrade but after this happened twice I gave up.

Comment: I think you should mark your answer as correct

Comment: This worked for me: http://kig.re/2014/12/31/how-to-use-arduino-nano-mini-pro-with-CH340G-on-mac-osx-yosemite.html

Answer (score 3):

The CH340 is a chip with notoriously iffy driver support, definitely for OS X, and reportedly also for Windows. Some driver authors are not very fond of it, as evidenced by this [affectionate comment](http://cvsweb.netbsd.org/bsdweb.cgi/src/sys/dev/usb/uchcom.c?rev=1.13&content-type=text/x-cvsweb-markup&only_with_tag=MAIN)

```
/*
 * driver for WinChipHead CH341/340, the worst USB-serial chip in the world.
 */
```

On the upside, the chip costs an order of magnitude less than the commonly used FTDI chips.

I've seen drivers from 3 sources:

1. The manufacturer drivers work off and on. The ones on the official site are not signed, and at some point, they started causing kernel panics for me.
2. The [Codebender](https://codebender.cc) team is including free CH340 drivers in their installer, and I've had some success running those, although I'm having some difficulties with the latest version. YMMV.
3. So far, the drivers developed by [Repleo](https://www.mac-usb-serial.com) have been rock solid for me. These are commercial, but, at less than $10, a pretty good deal in my opinion.

Answer (score 3):

On MacOS Sierra it kept crashing the OS,  but version 1.3 works on MacOS Sierra.

Found here:  https://github.com/adrianmihalko/ch340g-ch34g-ch34x-mac-os-x-driver

Comment: Yep. That works. :-)